# Remove timestamp from column of strings where not all rows contain a date/time

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I have a df as screenshot below:
[image]

I have a column, `Completed` that contains strings, that are either a date or the word `'No'` (as in date of order completion or not completed).
I want to remove the timestamp from the rows that contain it, but whenever I try to use something like `pd.to_datetime` on the column I get an error as it cannot parse the rows containing `'No'`.

Can anybody suggest what I can try please?